# While my elsevier in press article shows up on the journal website, it has not appeared in Google Scholar after a week

Tags: publications, online-publication, google-scholar, elsevier

While my Elsevier in-press article shows up on the journal website, it has not yet appeared in Google scholar after a week. Is this normal and part of the process? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes it can take some time. Don't worry - it will show up soon.

Comment: My advisor recalled of a time that to submit a paper you had to type it and send by letter. It would take months to get a response and the reviews, and after all the troubles and if you were lucky you would get a printed journal with your paper. They considered it a jump in technology when the department installed a fax machine! Leap forward, now we complain because an automatic online list, that crawls through hundreds of publishers and thousands of papers didn't list our paper after 1 week of acceptance.

Comment: I'm curious - is your paper there by now? Facing a similar problem

Comment: @AmirSagiv Hi Amir. Congratulations on your new paper. Yeah. it appeared on Google Scholar after a short time, but I can't recall how much time it took. Anyway, I think you should be patient. Meanwhile, you can share your new publication on social networks to get more attention. It works a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Google Scholar updates on its own unpredictable schedule, based on whatever sort of web-crawling and internal processing schedules Google happens to be running with it.  Sometimes I find that it updates almost immediately, other times not for more than a month.

In short: don't worry about it.  If it's on the website of a reputable publisher, then it will show up sooner or later, and usually within just a couple weeks of publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Have patience! Google scholar will find it. Give it some time!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had that issue with a paper and decided to add it manually. When I hit the "Add" button (which appears at the top of your publication list if you are logged in and viewing your own profile), I found that the paper was already in one of the groups under "Select groups of articles that you have authored from the list below," it just hadn't actually been added to my profile. I selected it and it was added with no further hassles.

On another occasion, I did add the article manually. Months later, it was also added automatically by Google Scholar, and I was able to merge the two versions.